# Determine whether subset $W$ is subspace of vector space $V=M^{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I know how to check if a subset involving polynomials is a subspace of a  Vector space, but this question is really stumping me. Any help would be much appreciated.

> Determine if subset $$W = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} : b + d = 0 \right\}$$ is a subspace of the vector space $V=M^{2\times2}$

Answer (score 1):

It is. You simply have to check the three properties:

- $0\in W$,
- $A,B\in W$ implies $A+B\in W$ and
- $A\in W$ implies $\lambda A \in W$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
the matrices of $W$ have the form 
$$
W =\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&-b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\in W
$$
now check for
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&-b
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y\\
z&-y
\end{bmatrix}
\quad and \quad k
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&-b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
have the same form $W$.